# Regex to parse a shortcode into an array

Tags: arrays, regex, shortcode

I have a shortcode. I want to extract all the attributes and their values and put them into an array.

This is the shortcode:

```
[res_map address="Yeronga QLD 4104, Australia" description="<img src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/responsive-maps-plugin/includes/img/company.png'> {br} Yeronga QLD 4104, Australia {br} Phone:  0040 752 235 756" directionstext="(directions to our address)" icon="blue" iconsize="" style="2" scalecontrol="no" typecontrol="no" streetcontrol="no" locateme="no" zoom="13" zoomcontrol="no" draggable="yes" scrollwheel="no" searchbox="no" clustering="no" logging="no" poi="yes" fullscreen="no" width="100%" height="500px" maptype="roadmap" popup="no" center="" refresh="yes" key="private_key"]
```

The **description** attribute can have any HTML content in it. I need to create an array from this shortcode, like this:

```
address=>Yeronga QLD 4104, Australia

description=><img src='http://local.....lia {br} Phone:  0040 752 235 756

directionstext=>(directions to our address)

icon=>blue
```

etc the other attributes too.

What is the correct Regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution only works, if there are no `"` inside a string:

```
\s?\[?([^=]+)="([^"]*)"\]?
```

- `\s?\[?`: whitespace and `[` should not be included in a key, therefore matching before the actual group match
- `([^=]+)=`: matches a group with every character up to a `=`
- `"([^"]*)"`: matches a group inside `"`
- `\]?`: matches an optional `]`

Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/DGaRCo/1

Comment: There are no " inside a string. You were fast :) The solution works, thank you so much!